# gtk How to highlight the next line of textview?

Tags: textview, gtk, highlight

i have to highlight only the second line (arr[ii+1]). I'm tryng to remove previous tag with two iterators and add the highlight to new line with others one :

```
                                sprintf(bufferS,"%s",arr[ii]);

                            if(cuno==0)
                            {
                               gtk_text_buffer_get_end_iter(buffer, &ei);
                               gtk_text_buffer_insert(buffer, &ei, bufferS, -1);
                               gtk_text_buffer_get_end_iter(buffer, &ei);
                               gtk_text_buffer_insert(buffer, &ei, "\n", -1);
                               cuno++;
                            }

                               sprintf(bufferS2,"%s",arr[ii+1]);


                               gtk_text_buffer_create_tag(buffer, "gray_bg","background", "gray", NULL);
                               gtk_text_buffer_get_end_iter(buffer, &ei2);
                               gtk_text_buffer_get_end_iter(buffer, &ei);
                               gtk_text_buffer_insert(buffer, &ei2, bufferS2, -1);
                               gtk_text_buffer_get_end_iter(buffer, &ei2);
                               gtk_text_buffer_insert(buffer, &ei2, "\n", -1);
                               gtk_text_buffer_get_start_iter(buffer, &si2);
                               gtk_text_buffer_get_start_iter(buffer, &si);
                               gtk_text_buffer_remove_all_tags(buffer,&si, &ei);
                               gtk_text_buffer_apply_tag_by_name(buffer, "gray_bg",&si2, &ei2);
```

but on output the text is ever all highlighted, someone can help me?Thank you

Comment: Does anybody know how to highlights a string in a textview?In this case is the content of arr[ii+1] and remove the previous tag,
thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

Resolved with this one, Thank you :)

```
   gtk_text_buffer_create_tag(buffer, "gray_bg","background", "green", NULL);
   gtk_text_buffer_get_iter_at_line(buffer,&si,ii+1);
   gtk_text_buffer_get_iter_at_line_offset (buffer,&ei2,ii+1,lstr);
   gtk_text_buffer_remove_tag_by_name (buffer,"gray_bg",&start,&end);
   gtk_text_buffer_apply_tag_by_name(buffer, "gray_bg",&si, &ei2);
```